# How do you paass command line arguments to a shell script converted into an app using playtpus?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, platypus

I have tried using pyinstaller on my Mac to distribute a python that takes command line arguments but it is failing to run saying missing lib error. So I thought I’d try platypus bundled python app. Can I pass command line arguments to the platypus app?